# php code to insert all Years between two selected years

Tags: php, cakephp

i am using cakephp..

I have **fromyear** and **ToYear** **fields** in my form

i want if i select fromYear = 2013 and ToYear = 2016

then it insert 3 rows in database like below example..

```
 fromyear   
     2013 
     2014
     2015
     2016    

        like wise...

        please help me to get above scenario..
```

i have tried below code...but this is inserting same from year in all rows...but i want to insert all year between selected years.

```
public function addVin(){
        $this->layout = "backend";
        if($this->request->is('post')){       
            $this->loadModel('VinStore');
            $from = $this->request->data['VinStore']['FromYear'];
            $to = $this->request->data['VinStore']['ToYear'];
            if((!empty($from)) && (!empty($to))) { 
                $count = $from - $to;
                for ($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++) {  
                    $this->VinStore->create();                
                    $this->VinStore->save($this->request->data);
                }
                $this->Session->setFlash("Vin Data has been added");
                $this->redirect('/admins/addVin'); 
            }       

        }

    }
```

Comment: You would have to show us the code for `$this->VinStore->save();` before we would be sure what the fairly obvious error is

Comment: but i put my complete function code there...i am working on cakephp 2.0...

Comment: Need to see the method that you are calling (probably incorrectly) to save the data `$this->VinStore->save($this->request->data);`

Comment: i have more fields in my form instead of fromyear..here this is my from year field...MDL_YR..plz suggest me how to resolve this..i am new to cakephp...

Comment: I cannot help unless you post the code from the `->save()` function

Comment: you want printr of save data()...

Comment: Which field are you trying to save the year to?

Comment: no i dont want to save Toyear in my table...i only want to save fromyear in my table....suppose i select fromyear = 2012 and toyear = 2017 then it insert fromyear = 2012,2013,2014.....2017 in table....thats it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function addVin(){
    $this->layout = "backend";
    if($this->request->is('post')){      
        $this->loadModel('VinStore');       
            $from = $this->request->data['VinStore']['MDL_YR'];
            $to = $this->request->data['VinStore']['MDL_YR_To'];
            $count = $to - $from; 
            for ($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++) {  
                $year = $from++;
                $this->request->data['VinStore']['MDL_YR'] = $year;
                $this->VinStore->create();                
                $this->VinStore->save($this->request->data);
                $to--;
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash("Vin Data has been added");
            $this->redirect('/admins/addVin'); 



    }
```